# How to monitor network traffic node.js and Windows libraries

Tags: node.js

Hi I want to monitor / capture TCP/UDP and other information using node.js, is there any module that can help me ?
I am looking at [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) and other modules but I could not figure out how to do that.
node.js has a module os and I can list network interfaces using that module, but how can I find all traffic passing through that interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [cap module](https://github.com/mscdex/cap) to monitor network traffic. If you are on Windows, make sure you have [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm) installed.

Comment: can i block unwanted IP's ? or a list of Ips

Comment: It's monitoring only. If you need actually filter/block traffic, then you need to look at (creating a binding for) [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows and/or netfilter/iptables on *nix. For the latter there is a [wrapper library](https://github.com/diosney/node-netfilter) on npm. I do not know of any existing bindings for WFP for node.js though.